# How old was E.T.?

Tags: age, et-the-extra-terrestrial

In *E.T.: the Extra-Terrestrial*, the titular character acts pretty immaturely at times.

For example, he

- follows a random, obviously planted candy trail, on a hostile planet,

  [image: Elliot leaving a trail of Reese's Pieces]
- drinks alcohol without understanding the repercussions,

  [image: E.T. drinking beer]
- and gets super-emotionally invested in a movie, to the point of subconsciously using a psychic link to get someone to recreate a scene from it.

  [image: Elliot kissing his classmate]

Canonically, was he young or immature, or was he just a member of a fairly naïve species?

Comment: 1.  Who *doesn't* eat trails of mysterious candy? 2.  His planet probably doesn't have Coors, so he didn't know it was alcohol (because he clearly didn't know that Coors is terrible).  3.  This site is full of people who are strangely emotionally invested in movies.  Your name is "Rogue Jedi" for that very reason.  I don't see the problem here.  :P

Comment: @WadCheber He was so emotionally invested that he created some sort of psychic link to get someone to recreate the scene. That's not typical.

Comment: [These people](http://3m1yvb3ekpj045f9t02a2ryq.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/388031_433782169999635_894684162_n.jpg) do that without anyone psychically forcing them to do so.

Comment: None of this establishes that he was immature. He's clearly naive about Earth culture, just like you're (presumably) naive about what life is like on his planet. Unless you travel more than I suspect.

Comment: @anaranjada I assume not following random, obviously planted food trails on a hostile planet isn't a solely human thing.

Comment: <Stops eating trail of Reese's Pieces found on floor and looks up>  Wha?  I mean, yeah, of course people don't really eat obviously planted trails of candy.  Why would anyone be that stu- <trap falls on head>

Comment: *"follows a random candy trail, on a hostile planet,"* If he was psychic he probably judged danger according to sensing the mind of a predator (psychically). Since the kid meant him no harm, and was actually asleep if my recollection of the scene is correct (have not seen the entire movie), he would've sensed no danger - and been correct about that. ..just musing.

Comment: @RogueJedi: "That's not typical." - I'm interested to read about your empirical evidence for what *is* typical among a civilization of psychics ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### He's ten million years old.

From the novelisation by William Kotzwinkle (emphasis mine):

> The planet was unspeakably strange. **He was ten million years old** and had been a great many places, but he'd never encountered anything as complicated as this. Overwhelmed, he crept away, needing to rest his brain in the vegetable patch. He slumped down next to a cabbage and lowered his head. It was all over.

I've also read that he's actually relatively young among members of his species, but can't find a canonical quote for this (I don't actually have the book to hand, although I read it several years ago).

Comment: Ten million years in his own reference frame, or in that of his home planet? You could live to ten million years old if you did laps around the solar system at nearly the speed of light.

Comment: Guy who [traveled thousands of light years in a spaceship](http://www.fantastic-plastic.com/E.T.SpaceshipPhoto.JPG) and built an intergalactic telephone out of [a Speak and Say, walkie talkie, umbrella, coffee can, and tin foil](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_Yaoe2Ha8Lpk/ShYp9xeqQQI/AAAAAAAAE4U/sfefvj_Pd8w/s1600/73_1983.jpg) finds 1982 earth more complicated than anything he's ever seen.  Got it.

Comment: @RogueJedi - You're thinking of Reese's Peanut Butter Cups.  Reese's Pieces are basically M&Ms with peanut butter *instead of* chocolate.  There ain't no chocolate in Reese's Pieces.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BDsgIoI.jpg

Comment: I still have the book... leafing through it I can't really find where he's supposed to be young for his species. Only sentences like "He was old, but he moved well, faster than most ten-million-year botanists with feet like marsh ducks".

Comment: A novelisation quote? For shame.

Comment: @Valorum Hark at potorum call kettal'thor black.

Comment: @WadCheber [Robot Chicken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0AOEj_JKOQ) says that ET was... special. On the side note, "Road not taken" is a great story about huge galactic empire that invented FTL but is stuck at a level of black-powder muskets, so indeed kids bike might be a marvel of engineering ;)

Comment: Oh, yeah. The team know they've been spotted, they're hurrying to complete their mission, to collect as many plants as possible before they are forced to take off, and then our ET goes for a leisure stroll, to look at the dwellings of the locals. You know what, senile, that's the word.